# Animating Images in React without reloading image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using React to load and render images as items of a carousel component. I am using the `useState` hook to set the currently active carousel item, and when a user clicks the next or back arrow, I use the `set` function of the `useState` hook to update the active item. I then use CSS animations to animate the rotation of the carousel items.

However, with this implementation, the component re-requests the image asset every time the carousel's active item changes, causing a flash on the image.

Here is how it's currently set up to handle animating the carousel.

```
// Component
const Carousel = ({ data }: Props) => {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(0)

  const back = () => {
    const newActive = activeItem - 1
    setActiveItem(newActive < 0 ? slice.items.length - 1 : newActive)  
  }

  const next = () => {
    const newActive = activeItem + 1
    setActiveItem(newActive % slice.items.length)
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="carousel-container">
        <button onClick={back}>Back</button>
        <div className="carousel">
          items.forEach((item, i) => {
            let itemClass = "slide"
            if (i === activeItem-1) itemClass += " prev"
            else if (i === activeItem) itemClass += " active"
            else if (i === activeItem+1) itemClass += " next"
            else itemClass += " hidden"

            return <CarouselItem item={item} className={itemClass} />
          })
        </div>
        <button onClick={next}>Next</button>
      </div>
    </section>

  )

}

// SCSS
.carousel {
  .item {
    transition: transform 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.28, 0.11, 0.3, 1.01), box-shadow 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.28, 0.11, 0.3, 1.01);
    &.prev {
       z-index: 0;
       transform: translate3d(-35%, 0, -30px);
    }
    &.active {
       z-index: 1;
       transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0px);
    }
    &.next {
       z-index: 0;
       transform: translate3d(35%, 0, -30px);
    }
    &.hidden {
       z-index: -1;
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, -50px);
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get this component to update it's state (i.e. animate the rotation of the carousel) without re-requesting the already loaded images?